# ember.js - save() resetting DS.attr('date') model properties

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm working on a `ember.js 1.2.0` application and am currently using the `DS.Adapter` of `Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.3` in combination with `moment.js 2.0.0` I have multiple input screens which I switch to with Handlebars `if` structures. My controller looks something like this:

```
step1Action: function () {
    this.get('currentModel').set('property1', moment()); //DS.attr('date')
    this.get('currentModel').set('property2', 'SomeString');
    this.set('isStep2', true);
},
step2Action: function () {
    this.get('currentModel').set('property3', moment()); //DS.attr('date')
    this.get('currentModel').save();
}
```

The problem I'm having is that after saving, `property1` and `property3` are set back to `null` on calling `save()`, while `property2` is set correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used moment.js before, but it seems as if you're using the `moment()` function wrong. That function seems to return some kind of special object specific to that library. The date parser for Ember Data expects a Javascript `Date` object. You can get a `Date` instance with `moment()._d`.

Comment: Your right! I thought it wouldn't be a problem because my Fixtures used the moment.js Object and it worked fine - I guess ember doesn't do any checks for Fixtures and display, whats why all worked fine until now - Thanks!